# How to get contact image url in python xmpp

Tags: python, linux, xmpp

Using python xmpp am able to connect to gtalk and send messages.
But how to get the user's profile pic ?

Answer (score 1):

I did that a couple of years ago using [xmppony](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xmppony) which is a fork of xmpppy

http://codingteam.net/project/jabberclient/browse/trunk/jabber/vcard.py